# Convergence of the series $\sum a^{\sum \frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to find the values of $a \in \mathbb{R}^+$ for which the following sum converges. $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a^{\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n}}$$

We get, by ratio Test, $$\left|\frac{a^{\sum_{n=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{n}}}{a^{\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n}}}\right| = a^{\frac{1}{k+1}} \geq 1 \text{ if } a\geq 1$$
and so the series diverges if $a\geq 1$.

But how do I handle the case for $0
<a < 1$ ?

P.S. $\mathop {\lim \sup }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left|\frac{a^{\sum_{n=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{n}}}{a^{\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n}}}\right| = 1.$ So, that's inconclusive (by Theorem 3.34 of Baby Rudin.)

Comment: I would recommend finding a slightly different title. As-is, it's just a formula which tells us nothing about the problem you're trying to solve. (ie. Are you looking for a closed-form equivalent expression? Convergance/divergance?)

Comment: Oh yes ! Thanks.

Comment: For the sum, do you mean $\sum_{n = 1}^k \frac{1}{n}$? Because otherwise $\sum_{n = 1}^k \frac{1}{k} = 1$.

Comment: You can use $$
\log k < \sum\limits_{n = 1}^k {\frac{1}{n}}  < \log k + 1.
$$

Comment: @0XLR Yeah! Got confused by my own notations. Changed it.

Comment: @Gary You could use that in conjunction with the root test, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We compute
\begin{align*}
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to  + \infty } k\left( {\frac{{a^{\sum\nolimits_{n = 1}^k {\frac{1}{n}} } }}{{a^{\sum\nolimits_{n = 1}^{k + 1} {\frac{1}{n}} } }} - 1} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to  + \infty } k\left( {a^{ - \frac{1}{{k + 1}}}  - 1} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to  + \infty } k\left( {e^{ - \frac{1}{{k + 1}}\log a}  - 1} \right) =  - \log a.
\end{align*}
By Raabe's test the series converges when $-\log a>1$, i.e., $0<a<e^{-1}$ and diverges when $a>e^{-1}$. To check the convergence for $a=e^{-1}$, we use $
\sum\nolimits_{n = 1}^k {\frac{1}{n}} <\log k +1$, to find
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {e^{ - \sum\nolimits_{n = 1}^k {\frac{1}{n}} } }  \ge e^{ - 1} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {e^{ - \log k} }  = e^{ - 1} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{k}} .
$$
But the harmonic series diverges, hence the series diverges when $a=e^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't know about Raabe's test.

Comment: You can find several tests here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests