# For what a, b does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{c_n}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

**Problem:**
For what a, b does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{c_n}$ converge where $c_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{b+k}$? Suppose that $a,b$ are positive.

**My attempt:**

In order to show convergence, we have to get an upper bound. We realize that $a^{c_n} = e^{\ln(a) c_n}$ where $c_n \leq \frac{1}{b}+\int_{0}^{n} \frac{1}{b+x}dx = \frac{1}{b} + \ln(1+\frac{n}{b})$ using the integral test.

Substitution back into our original expression for the sum gives us that:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{c_n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{\ln(a) (\frac{1}{b} + \ln(1+\frac{n}{b}))} = a^{1/b} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^{\ln(1+\frac{n}{b})}$

I can from here realize that if we would fixate $b$, the only way for this to *eventually* converge is if $0 < a < 1$. With that said, it isn't guaranteed.

However, the answer tells me that $0 <a < 1/e$, and I don't really know how to get to there from here. I thought that I could somehow use the fact that $\ln(1+n/b) = \ln(n/b) + \ln(1+b/n)$ where I can then use some sort of Maclaurin expansion for the last term. However, this only seemed to complicate things even more. I'd be glad if you could share any ideas that could help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: This recent question may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317247/convergence-of-the-series-sum-a-sum-frac1n/4317267

Comment: @Gary Thank you, the link helped me solve it :)

Comment: One problem with your analysis is that you assumed that if $c_n \le d_n$ for all $n$ (where $d_n$ is your bounding expression), then $a^{c_n} \le a^{d_n}$. But that is only true when $a > 1$, wheteas this is only convergent when $a < 1$